# Clicking Kendo Panelbar causes page to jump to top on mobile devices

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-panelbar

I have a Kendo UI panelbar on a website I'm developing, with a large number of panels (dynamic, but it can be up to 12).  On mobile devices, I've found that clicking a panel bar to expand or collapse it will also cause the page to jump to the top.  Since the panels are a bit further down the page, we're finding this to be really annoying.  It does not happen on a desktop screen though, even if I shrink the window down to about a mobile size (it **does** happen when I use Chrome's mobile emulation setting, however).  Is there a way that I can prevent this from happening?

EDIT: This behavior only occurs with panels that have a Kendo Grid within them, which is most of them; it does NOT occur with panels that just have text.

Comment: your issue is on the resize of display?

Comment: It happens with smaller device screens sizes, yes, but not so far if I just reduce the window size on a desktop.

Comment: so what you dont use media queries?